# Disable the autohide feature in the Ubuntu menubar

Tags: menu-bar, autohide

Is there any way to prevent the menu items in the global menu bar from hiding until mouseover? I really like the idea of the menubar, but it really gets me that the items disappear. Is there a way to make them permanently visible, like with the OS X menubar?

Comment: Showing/Hiding the menus appear to be hardcoded to the mouse entering/leaving the panel events. This doesn't seem to be exposed to a configuration setting.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the launcher? If so, you have to go to the "System Settings", than open "Appearance" and then go to "Behavior". There you can switch off the Auto-hide function of the launcher.

Comment: No, the menubar at the top (file, edit, view, help etc). Thanks anyway though!